# Different appsettings for customer in docker image

Tags: azure, docker, .net-core

How I can create docker image with different setting for each customer ?
Setting are stored in appseetings.json file

I'm using GitLab for CI (there I create docker image)
I'm using Azure for CD (Web app container service)
I have two separate projects that have to deploy for each customer. 
(Auth service and WebApi service) 
I have different settings for customer like smtp server, auth endpoints and so on (exactly these stuff I want to inject differently)

First mind was to create different images for each client, but after googling it became clear that I will have a lot of headache to support that.

I've seen a lot of info about environment variables, but they are relate to modes like staging, production and think that not suits to my case.

Other mind was that I have to store settings somewhere (store on Azure in my case).

Any case is use https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/
But it will create few docker images

I expect to create one docker image with different settings, but can't understand correct way to implement that.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually environment variables are well suited for your case. If you load them like this:

```cs
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
var config = builder.Build();
//...
var smptUrl = config.GetValue<string>("smtpUrl");
```

It will override your appsettings.json settings. On Azure you can change it in container settings. If you manually run docker you can change it via cli: `docker run -e VARIABLE=VALUE`. In above case it could be: `docker run -e smtpUrl=smtp.customer1.com`

Here is how to set it on Azure for docker containers:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-environment-variables

Comment: Maybe I missed something, but if I have ten different environments? I have to create ten a little bit different docker images. I working on configuration in azure - seems that's correct way, but stuck for now.

Comment: No, you create one image. Then when you run it, you just modify Env variables. In example I provided, what will happen if I run exactly the same image with:
`docker run -e smtpUrl=smtp.customer1.com`,
`docker run -e smtpUrl=smtp.customer2.com`,
`docker run -e smtpUrl=dev.server.local`?
Application inside will read `smtpUrl` differend for each run, and communicate with proper smtp service

Comment: Oh, I've got you point. But in case that I'm running these images on Azure (Azure app service) I can't understand how I can do that correctly. Thanks

Comment: on Azure in app service you have Configuration. Things you will set there will be seen as environment variables for your application.

Comment: yes, I setup variables, but they don't affect application. I've used double underscore to setup. Restarted app and nothing happens. I have api controller that returns me string of appsettings, and they stay the same

Comment: please check it here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-environment-variables

Comment: I've read that article. Thanks anyway.
I understood that I have to setup these variables before deployment and probably I missed something.